# Making sure android app is running

Tags: android, timer, notifications

I have developed an android app that needs to run in the background and alert the user after a certain amount of time. The problem is I have is that if I set the time and do something else on the phone, the notification doesn't come through. (I tested this by setting the timer for 10 minutes). Is there a way to make sure the app is always open in the background?

Comment: An app running in the background will drain the battery fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you use a Service? If not, it is definitely not running in the background. As soon as an Activity is withdrawn from focus, its onPuase method is invoked and it stops running (see [Activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#Lifecycle)). To make your app working in the background you need to implement a [Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html).